# Comparing substrings with whole strings - split function advanced

Tags: vba, split

I have code which works very well for comparing the range **(Col B) in sheet 2** to the range **(col A) in sheet 1**. Upon finding a match, it then copies the adjacent values from **sheet 1 (col B)** into **sheet 2 (col C).**

> [Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF9U9.png)    [Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCkWN.png)    [Sheet 2 current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTWF5.png)

My only issue is that the code does not work for the case that **(col A) in sheet 1** has more than one word in each of the cells.

Any suggestions on how I can get the code to compare not only single words (which it works well for), but also to find and compare two words in order and adjacently? E.g If I have "temperature ramp" in **Sheet 1 (Col A)**, and I have "Perform a temperature ramp" in **(Col B) Sheet 2**, I would like the code to be able to find "temperature ramp".

This is *in addition* to the code comparing as it does now for single words in (Col A).

The sheet examples and the solution that this code gives is as below: The code removes the temperature ramp, but I would need it to recognize both words together, and if there is no recognition that it keeps the line there without deleting it?

```
Sub x()

    Dim v, vOut(), i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, va, r As Range, r1 As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet 1") 'Assumes list of words in A1/B1 and down on "Sheet 1"
        Set r = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet 2") 'Assumes phrases in B1 and down on "Sheet 2"
        v = .Range("B3", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
        .Columns(2).ClearContents
    End With

    ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(v) * r.Rows.Count, 1 To 2)

    For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
        va = Split(v(i, 1))
        For j = LBound(va) To UBound(va)
           For r1 = 1 To r.Rows.Count
            If LCase(Application.Trim(va(j))) Like "*" & LCase(r.Cells(r1, 1)) Then

            'If LCase(Application.Trim(va(j))) = LCase(r.Cells(r1, 1)) Then
                k = k + 1
                vOut(k, 1) = v(i, 1)
                vOut(k, 2) = r.Cells(r1, 2)
            End If
           Next r1
        Next j
    Next i

    Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("B3").Resize(k, 2) = vOut 'Puts results in B1/C1 and down on "Sheet2"

    End Sub
```

Comment: show your coding efforts to reach the goal and detail the issues you met

Comment: Hi @DisplayName, To be honest I am stumped at this one. I haven't tried this idea out as I don't know how I would go about it, but I was wondering if you could set the integer value that is determined by "va" above equal to "n" for example, which is the total number of sub-strings within each sentence in col B sheet 2. From there, you could then use another split function contained within an ElseIF, that if the original If function doesn't find a match, that the elseif can be used to compare an increasing portion of the sentence? The goal wouldn't require comparison of more than 2 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this is similair to your logic. Necessary notes in comments.

```
Sub CustomCopy()
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet, Sheet1ColA As Variant, Sheet2ColB As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long: k = 3
    Dim isFound As Boolean: IsFound = False
    Set sheet1 = Sheets(1)
    Set sheet2 = Sheets(2)
    'read both columns
    Sheet1ColA = sheet1.Range("A1:B" & sheet1.Cells(sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    Sheet2ColB = sheet2.Range("B3:B" & sheet2.Cells(sheet2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    'clear second and third column in second sheet
    sheet2.Range("B3:B" & sheet2.Cells(sheet2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    sheet2.Range("C3:C" & sheet2.Cells(sheet2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    For i = LBound(Sheet2ColB) To UBound(Sheet2ColB)
        isFound = False
        For j = LBound(Sheet1ColA) To UBound(Sheet1ColA)
            'perform case insensitive (partial) comparison
            If InStr(1, LCase(Sheet2ColB(i, 1)), LCase(Sheet1ColA(j, 1))) > 0 Then
                sheet2.Cells(k, 2) = Sheet2ColB(i, 1)
                sheet2.Cells(k, 3) = Sheet1ColA(j, 2)
                k = k + 1
                isFound = True
            End If
        Next
        If Not isFound Then
            sheet2.Cells(k, 2) = Sheet2ColB(i, 1)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly for more than one word! Cannot thank you enough Michal, you made it look so easy. Any advice on the last pointer, just that the array doesn't delete any of the sentences in Col B sheet 2 that it doesn't find a match for, and keeps them in the same order?

Comment: Turczyn, that is exactly what I needed. Cannot thank you enough! This problem has been plaguing me for so long lol

Comment: Sorry Michael, one last point, sheet 2 col B will start from cell B3. When I input this into the above code it seems to always paste the new material in at B1? I will have headers in B1 and B2, and likewise in C1 and C2 so it would be preferable to not have these being cleared also? Sorry to ask so much, I can pose a new question for this if you like?

Comment: it oddly seems to delete cell C2 value but pastes the new material starting from cell C3? Other than that, it is absolutely spot on!

Comment: It's impossible.. I don't reference C2 at all in this code. Glad to help :)

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well, no matter what cell reference I put e.g. tried "C4:C", it still removes the C2 cell... very strange? Maybe need to restart my excel?

Comment: Don't know if you understand why this is happening, but if I run this code with text only in cell C1 and C2, it deletes what is in C2. If I put text into C3 it deletes everything from C3 downwards? Is there a reason that the code does this? I tried changing the cells( reference but didn't change anything? Any thoughts?